# Purpose of the Triple Angle Formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, education

What is the Triple Angle Formula used for? Is there any way to actually apply it to a real-life scenario? Is there maybe a word problem I can practice with? There's not much examples online.
This is the formula: $\sin3\theta = 3\sinθ−4\sin^3\theta$

Comment: It's key to solving certain [cubic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_solution_for_three_real_roots).

Comment: Well, what sorts of applications do you like to use the double angle formula for?

Comment: Your Question would be greatly improved by giving the formula that you want to know applications of.  See [the introduction to posting mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), or post in "ASCII math" and we can help with formatting.  Most likely you having in mind the sine or the cosine of three times an angle, but other "triple angle formulas" are possible.